# DropDownList and GridView databind combination

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I would appreciate, if you could help me;-)

There is a web page to view data from DB, I use GridView control.

Next I put 4 DropDownLists, and they are either bound to other tables from the same DB. These tables have connections to each other (one to one).

Question:

1. I can get all data out from DB on gridview (for this reason I use a View).
2. When I bind the Dropdownlists and try to make filter, my gridview is completely empty :-((

**How can i bind (4) dropdownlists in that way, thay my gridview could show  data accordingly?**

Here's my Select query:

```
SELECT * FROM [general_view] WHERE (([Surname] = @Surname) AND ([Letter_type] = @Letter_type) AND ([Sent_number] = @Sent_number) AND ([DocType] = @DocType))
```

p.s.: I would also like to give zhe client  the opportunity to choose all data from DB. How can I show all data on gridview after dropdownlists are bound and filter is working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you bind the drop down to db?. Just show that code problem might be there.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="EmployeeDDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="auto-style39" Height="25px" Width="200px" DataSourceID="EmployeeSqlDS" DataTextField="Surname" DataValueField="Employee_ID">
                         </asp:DropDownList>